# Convert double number to float number

Tags: python, matlab, floating-point, type-conversion, double

I need to do some elaborations on MATLAB data in Python.
The data is stored as an array of `doubles` in Matlab. When I retrieve it, despite being stated [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handle-data-returned-from-matlab-to-python.html) that `double` data types from Matlab are converted in `float` data types when handled by Python, I get this error:

> TypeError: unorderable types: double() < float()

What I'm trying to do is this

```
import matlab.engine

eng=matlab.engine.connect_matlab()

x = eng.workspace['MyData']
x = x[len(x)-1]
if x < 0.01:
    #do stuff
```

How can I convert the `double` number stored in the array to a `float` so that I can use it alongside my other Python variables?

Comment: Have you tried float(x) < 0.01?

Comment: @DavidLeon yes, it only accepts int or strings as arguments, so no luck

Comment: what returns `type(x)`?

Comment: it returns mlarray.double

Comment: then try doing `np.array(x)` after your `x = eng.workspace` (np is for `import numpy as np`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting doubles into floats in Matlab is as simple as calling the [single function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html):

```
A = rand(10);
whos A;

B = single(A);
whos B;
```

As per console output:

```
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         10x10              800  double              

  Name       Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  B         10x10              400  single
```

Be careful about the loss of precision, since you are converting 64 bit numeric values into 32 bit numeric values.

**EDIT**

Since you can't manipulate your Matlab data, in order to accomplish this I suggest you to use either Numpy (refer to this function in case: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) or `struct` for a straight conversion (refer to this answer in case: [convert double to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291539/convert-double-to-float-in-python)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I cannot do any preelaboration on the data in Matlab, since it's coming from the simulation of a real plant implemented in simulink, and is practically untouchable. I need to do as much as possible in Python, if there is a way.

Comment: Are you using Numpy?

Comment: Actually no, is it helpful in this context?

Comment: For sure it can be helpful (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) but you have to change some logics into your Python code and learn to use that framework. Alternatively, if you want a quick and dirty solution, you can use `struct` for straight conversions (refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291539/convert-double-to-float-in-python).

Comment: I will take a look at the documentation. By the way, the solution you proposed in your answer still doesn't seem to work, it results in the same error only with 'single' instead of 'double'...

Comment: I eventually solved it using the numpy documentation you linked in the previous comment. If would like to edit your answer with that information, I can mark it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the feedback!